# Italy passport validity

Tags: passports, italy

I live in the US and have an Italian passport.

My passport expires mid-May 2024, and I am planning to travel to Italy end of November 2023 and return to the US mid-January 2024.

Apparently, I cannot renew my passport until after mid-November and it will take 3-4 weeks so not on time for my trip.

Given that I will leave Italy >3 months from expiration, am I able to use this expiring passport to enter Italy in November?

Thanks

Maurizio

Comment: As an Italian-US dual citizen you can also use your US passport to travel to Italy.  Should your right to enter or remain in Italy ever come into question, you can use any evidence of Italian nationality.

Comment: True. That would be Plan B but I would like to avoid the Schengen 90/180 constraints given the several US-IT-US trips already made this year!

Comment: Just to be sure that you are aware of it: renewing a passport in Italy is very difficult right now. Due to several circumstances there 's a really long wait, possibly several months. Having an air ticket should give you priority, but I recommend to do some research. Here's an [article](https://www.corriere.it/economia/consumi/cards/passaporti-fino-7-mesi-l-appuntamento-questura-sei-citta-nessuna-disponibilita/sei-citta-non-si-riesce-prendere-l-appuntamento.shtml) about this in Italian.

Comment: "That would be Plan B but I would like to avoid the Schengen 90/180 constraints given the several US-IT-US trips already made this year": Schengen 90-180 constraints do not apply to Italian citizens even if they use a US passport to enter the Schengen area.  If you exceed the 90-180 rule with a US passport you might face some inconvenience and an irritated border guard who has to decide whether to believe your claim of Italian citizenship, but if you have an expired Italian passport that is unlikely to happen.  In no case can you be fined or denied entry.

Comment: Also, nobody seems to have mentioned the _carta d'identità._  Do you have one?  If you do, you have no need for an Italian passport in the EU; the free movement directive specifies that the right to free movement may be exercised just as well with a national ID card as with a passport.

Answer (score 6):

You can always travel to and enter your country of citizenship with your passport as long as it is valid. There is never any requirement for your passport to have any extra validity beyond the date you will enter the country. Any extra validity requirements are only for foreigners entering the country, not nationals.

(Even if your passport is expired you can usually still enter the country, but you will most likely have a problem with the airline not allowing you to board).

Comment: Thanks. Very useful. I also carry a US passport which I can show the airline should they raise concerns.

Comment: @Maurizio While you may be able to enter Italy with an expired Italian passport (that is a fairly common immigration rule in many countries), you should also ascertain if you require a transit visa in any other country on the way to Italy.

Comment: Thanks. Next trip is straight US-IT-US. I will definitely renew my passport when I return in January to avoid any potential hassle.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica while your advice is sound in general, as a practical matter there are very few countries that require transit visas for citizens of Italy or the US, certainly not any countries through which one is likely to travel between Italy and the US.

Comment: @phoog Yes, that's certainly true. But we know from the question that the OP is not a seasoned international traveler. The possibility of a transit, although unlikely, was appropriate to bring to the OP's attention.

Comment: Speaking of me? Well, how do you define 'seasoned'?

Comment: @Maurizio Your question about an Italian citizen using a valid but close-to-expiring passport to return to Italy suggested my conclusion.  If I was in error, I apologize.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, and your recommendation is much appreciated. No need to apologize. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just received confirmation from the Italian Consulate in New York that travel between US and IT is still allowed even if the Italian passport expires within 6 months from the travel dates, provided the passport is *Valid*

Actually, even to return to the US the Italian passport is still valid 6 months **after** the expiration date.

https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2022-Mar/Six-Month%20Passport%20Validity%20Update%2020220316.pdf

Thank you all for your help on this matter.

Comment: The second part of your answer is not quite exact. Passports from those countries are exempt from the 6 months-after-departure-date requirement (which only applies to visitors, of course, not citizens or PRs). The passport must still be valid for the duration of the stay.

Comment: You are correct and apologies if I misinterpreted it but the title of the document was somewhat confusing: Countries That Extend Passport Validity for an Additional Six Months After Expiration

Comment: @jcaron anyway that rule applies to visitors.  Different rules apply to people who live in the US, depending on their status.  If Maurizio is also a US citizen then it doesn't matter when the Italian passport expires.

Comment: Maurizio: in fact, as a US-Italian dual citizen you must use your US passport to enter the US (in fact you ought to be able to talk your way in with an Italian passport in an emergency, but there is a law that says you are supposed to use the US passport, whereas Italy does not have an analogous law).  So really the only difficulty you would have flying to the US with an expired Italian passport would be on leaving the Schengen area.  And as with entering, an expired Italian passport should be enough to excuse you from any negative consequences for an apparent overstay.